# How to display AWS EC2 private ip address in ansible stdout?

Tags: ansible

I have the below playbook to display du for a list of ec2 hosts. However, with this, the output displays du and the corresponding public ip address. How can I modify this to display the output alongwith private IP address for the corresponding ec2 instances?

```
---

- hosts:  ec2_hosts
  tasks:
          - name: "display disk utilization"
            command: df -h /home
            register: show
          - debug: var=show.stdout_lines
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat crude way is just modify your `command`:

```
command: df -h /home && ip a
```

A bit cleaner would be when you specify the name of the interface of interest:

```
command: df -h /home && ip a show eth1
```

And the most readable would be to add one more task:

```
- name: Display interface configuration
  command: ip a show eth1
  register: ifc
```